# how to add toolbar XML layout in to my activity

Tags: toolbar

i watching the **Android Material Design** in YouTube part 3 about **Android ToolBar Example- Android Tutorial For Beginners** in this video add this code in the Main Activity

the toolbar error in the MainActivity is for what?
the error is

```
setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.toolbar) in AppCompatActivity cannot be applied to (android.Widget.Toolbar )
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you used `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, but in your `MainActivity`, you imported `android.widget.Toolbar`. It's different. You need change the import part.